# Upload image file ,Using Text Box and button in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

I have a requirement wherein I have a text box and beside it a button. When the user clicks on the button, I want file upload type action. Also, I have another text box and beside it a button. When user clicks on the reset button, I don't want to lose the image. Can anyone plz help me.

Textbox1 button1 --->I need functionality of file upload.
Textbox2 button2 ---->when click on it don't want to lose the image.

Comment: you should provide some code... Otherwise you can use google to search good samples for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not working?  Also, if you're uploading a file, why are you using a text input instead of a file input?

Comment: FileUploader is a textbox with a button, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to post code but reading between the lines....
Use the fileupload control [File Upload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx). Then once the file (presumably an image) is uploaded either store a reference to it in the database or store it in session / viewstate.

By the sounds of it you'll also want to populate an image with this data, so make sure to set the imageurl to be whatever the location of the file just uploaded was.

Then when postback is fired from button 2 you can just rebind the object based on what was stored after the upload.